# Delete block in catalog_category_layered xml with filters

Tags: layout, blocks, xml

We have a shop and want to remove a item from our left site in our category page and only if someone uses an filter in the category. So not in de default category, only when someone chooses for instance a color.

this is what I tried:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="left">
 <remove name="catalog.leftnav2" />
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

we want to remove the block catalog.leftnav2, and in the situation above it is deleted in also the default category.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

This is too dynamic to be solved only with XML. What you can do is create an own layout handle

```
<catalog_category_layered_with_filter>

    <reference name="left">
     <remove name="catalog.leftnav2" />
    </reference>

</catalog_category_layered_with_filter>
```

And apply it in an observer for the `controller_action_layout_load_before` event:

```
public function addHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if ($observer->getAction()->getFullActionName() === 'catalog/category/view'
      && count(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters())
    ) {
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_category_layered_with_filter');
    }
}
```